# When does the WordPress Answers day start and end?

Tags: discussion, badges

So I've been trying to visit the site regularly to earn the "enthusiast" badge, getting somewhere in the mid-20 day range, when somehow I missed a day.  Doesn't make sense to me unless I somehow visited twice in one day. My question is, what timezone is the site hosted in and when does the day begin, relative to GMT and US EST? 
[image: Screengrab from profile]

Comment: Maybe you knew this, but you can click the "47 days, 1 consecutive" to get a calendar of all the days you visited the site. Of course, you can't go back in time to fill up a missing day - [except for special occasions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime), so this is mainly useful for bosses and spouses who want to know where you spent all that time!

Comment: @Jan Fabry - Now I'm really sad.  I didn't know about the clicking the days, but when I did I got an unwelcome but logical surprise.  As mentioned the days count is contained in the browser cookie...what if you're a "browser-whore" that uses and visits with multiple browsers?  You get a swiss-cheese calendar. See image in link.

Comment: @Ray: I also use different browsers, but I'm logged in (via OpenID) in all of them, and it seems the day counter has no problem with this. (The day count must be stored server-side, otherwise people could change it to earn the "Fanatic" badge without visiting.) What link are you referring to? (I can't see your calendar, only you and the moderators can.)

Comment: @Jan Fabry I was too slow editing - Here's the link. http://www.sixfourweb.com/images/wpse/wpsedays.jpg

So two lessons learned from this: one, visit daily (considering UTC) on the same browser, and two-Only visit WPSE at the end of the day if you want to get any work done.
So two lessons learned from this: one, visit daily (considering UTC) on the same browser, and two-Only visit WPSE at the end of the day if you want to get any work done.

Comment: @Ray: I think one of them is from the meta site and one of them is from the main site. Yes, that's confusing: they are two different sites (that was historically the case for Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow), only the logins are shared and meta takes over your reputation from the main site.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - Good catch on the Meta vs Main Site.  I have much to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The day starts on 00:00 UTC.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start)

This site is part of the Stack Exchange network, and you can find answers on many questions related to them on the main Meta Stack Overflow site. [The FAQ is a good place to start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) (or a bad place, if you get lost and waste the rest of your day there)

Comment: You mean like time spent on WPSE and not working on a client site???

Comment: thanks for the link to the prior post.  I cleared my browser cookies and that wiped the information.

Comment: Ray, if Jan's post answers your question, please mark it as accepted so others can find the proper information easily. Thanks!

Comment: also note that the current UTC time (with adjustments to make sure the client matches our server time) is always displayed on your user drop down now.

Comment: @tnorthcutt - My Bad.  Thanks for the reminder